# fs.writeSync insert text in a var

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello i'm trying to insert my text in my var Directory in my config file is it possible ? i'm trying to use position but the problem with position is if my text is long it does not fit well

```
 const defaultFolderName = fs.readFileSync('config.js', {encoding: 'utf8'});
    
    const folderName = process.argv[2] || defaultFolderName;
    const fd = fs.openSync('config.js', 'r+');
    
    const PathName = folderName;
    
    const data = `${PathName}', `;
    
    fs.writeSync(fd, data, 246, 'utf8');
```

config.js

```
const config = {

  Directory: 'insertText',  

  movie: 'test',  


};

export default config;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read a javascript file as text? You could just import `config` from the file.

Comment: you're right but how can i insert my text in a var ?

Comment: You can't insert into the middle of a file. If you write at a location, it overwrites what's there, it doesn't insert.

Comment: `defaultFolderName` contains the entire file, not just the folder name. Why are you using that as the default value of `folderName`?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. What are you trying to write where?

Comment: that line was wrong i already fixed it

Comment: is okay to overwrites what's there but my problem is if my text is too long my second Var moves, I need to take a line break when text is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very misguided, but you can do it with a regular expression replacement.

```
if (process.argv[2]) {
    const oldConfig = fs.readFileSync('config.js', {encoding: 'utf8'});
    newConfig = oldConfig.replace(/Directory:\s*'.*',/, `Directory: '${process.argv}',`);
    fs.writeFileSync('config.js', newConfig, {encoding: 'utf8'});
}
```

Comment: thank you so much replace was the solution